# circular dependent incomplete templated types

Tags: c++, graph, g++, clang, incomplete-type

I am trying to create a graph data-structure in an adjacency-map style, however I am running into some problems with circularly dependent structs. I have tried doing a forward declaration, but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting `invalid use of incomplete type node_collection<int>`, which makes sense since I am forward declaring my types, but I would still like to get this working somehow.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct edge;
template<typename T> struct node;
template<typename T> using edge_collection = std::unordered_map<std::string, edge<T>>;
template<typename T> using edge_refference = typename edge_collection<T>::iterator;
template<typename T> using node_collection = std::unordered_map<std::string, node<T>>;
template<typename T> using node_refference = typename node_collection<T>::iterator;

template<typename T>
struct node {
    T data;
    std::vector<edge_refference<T>> outgoing_edges{};
    std::vector<edge_refference<T>> ingoing_edges{};
};

template<typename T>
struct edge {
    T data;
    node_refference<T> source;
    node_refference<T> target;
};

template<typename T>
struct graph {
    node_collection<T> nodes;
    edge_collection<T> edges;
};


int main() {
    graph<int> g{};
}
```

```bash
g++ main.cpp
```

What is *really* odd is that this works just fine when using `clang` on macos! I am only getting this issue on my linux PC.

Comment: No errors compiling the shown code with gcc 12 on Linux.

Comment: Huh... I am using g++ version 11.2.0 ... Maybe that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is not guaranteed to compile, although the specification of the language is somewhat lacking in this area.

Your variable in `main` requires instantiation of `graph<int>`, which in turn requires instantiation of `std::unordered_map<std::string, node<T>>`.

`std::unordered_map` does not promise that it can be instantiated with incomplete types. Therefore instantiation of `node<T>` may also happen at this point.

Instantiation of `node<T>` requires in turn that `edge_collection<T>` be complete in order to access its `::iterator` member to determine the type of `node<T>`'s member. But `edge_collection<T>` for the same reason as above may require instantiation of `edge<T>`. `edge<T>` in turn requires instantiation of `node_collection<T>` which is just `std::unordered_map<std::string, node<T>>` so that you now have circular dependence of the instantiations.

So you are just lucky if it happens to compile.

In practice compilers don't actually require that a class be complete when a member is accessed with `::` as the standard requires, but allow lookup of any member that has been declared before the member declaration which caused the implicit instantiation requiring the lookup. However even with that more permissive behavior you would need to be lucky that `iterator` is declared in `std::unordered_map` before any use of the value type that would require it to be complete.

The only containers that the standard currently guarantees can be used this way with incomplete types are `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::forward_list` (since C++17, none before).

---

Specifically for libstdc++ it seems that there is some intention to allow `std::unordered_map` to be usable with incomplete types, based on [this commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=64acc43de1e33616e43b239887a260eb4a51fcc7), which is likely the reason that it works in GCC 12, but not GCC 11. If incomplete types were supported by `std::unordered_map`, then your program would be fine.

Comment: Interesting... It would seem that the (ordered) map container is usable with incomplete types. I don't necessarily want to switch compiler and/or container type though. I don't really know how I should refactor the code to avoid incomplete type usage though

Comment: @Sillydan The same problem applies to `std::set` and `std::map`. You would be relying on implementation-specific behavior. It is not guaranteed to work for either according to the standard. I added a list of the containers which are guaranteed to allow incomplete types to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the very in-depth answer! I will see if I can find a better solution that works around this issue. It would be nice if the standard would look into guaranteeing usage of incomplete types for containers such as `std::unordered_map`, `std::map` and `std::set`, but I guess it's not a priority for them :-)

Comment: @Sillydan A simple solution would be to not use `::iterator` directly via alias, but to make `*_refference` actual types with the iterators as members instead. That way, because `std::vector` is fine with an incomplete type, there won't be an instantiation of that new struct and the instantiation cycle is broken.

Comment: @Sillydan But more importantly, `std::unordered_map` will invalidate iterators if inserting a new element causes a rehash. Then the whole design will fail. Have a look at other graph implementations to see alternative approaches.

Comment: @Sillydan It is not necessarily straight-forward to implement these classes so that instantiation with incomplete types is possible. That often requires some elaborate tricks to delay instantiations until the type is complete. The standard can only require that if implementers are able and willing to make these changes. Also, there is a fundamental problem with allowing incomplete types in that type traits of the container can then not depend on traits of the element type, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632098/why-is-stdis-copy-constructible-vstdvectormoveonlytype-true.

Comment: In my full code base, I have made efforts to make the graph read-only and only constructable by a special factory so rehashing and iterator invalidation should not be an issue. 
By the way: Really good idea making the `*_refference`s as structs themselves! It totally works and there's little to no compromise in the interface, since I can just overload the `->` and `*` operator.